# STM32 USB to I2C IAP bridge

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, bootloader

I have two STM32 boards (A and B) connected together via I2C. Board A can trigger the RESET- and the BOOT-Pins of Board B. Therefore it should be possible for Board A to use the system bootloader of board B.

I can connect to Board A via USB with STMCubeProgrammer. I want Board A to translate all the USB-Bootloader-commands to I2C-Bootloader-commands, to have Board A working just as a "Bootloader-Bridge" to Board B.

**PC** <-- USB --> **Board A** <-- I2C --> **Board B**

I found the stm32-mw-openbl  project, but it does:

> It allows all possible bootloader operations (Read, write, erase, jump...) into internal (Flash, SRAM, OTP...) or external memory using one of the available communication interfaces (USART, I2C, SPI, USB-DFU, FDCAN...).

so it "translates" Bus-Commands to memory-commands, but I need USB-command (slave) to I2C-command (master).

I found the Open source flash program for STM32 using the ST serial bootloader called "stm32flash" which does the I2C master. But it's not made for embedded, nor does it "fit" to the openbl-project. Is there some other project (or openbl extension, or...), that I just don't see, that does already something I want?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic here. That being said, writing a bootloader yourself shouldn't be that complicated given that you already have the USB and I2C hardware working. You will need pull resistors on critical pins of board B though, in case board A is slower to boot.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to answer, but how could your answer possibly help me? I don't have a problem with pullups, I don't have timing issues, and I didn't ask how complicate it is to write a bootloader by my own (I did this several times - I can roughly estimate the effort). Just wanted to know, if I have to do it from scratch, or if somebody implemented this kind of USB-I2C bootloader-bridge already and has a project/comment/idea already somewhere.

Comment: It's not an answer but a comment, telling you that your question risk getting closed as off-topic.